# datetimepicker works in every web browser except Firefox?

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

here is my HTML piece of code :

meta:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js"></script>
```

body:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="datetimepicker4">Date:</label>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' placeholder="Sélectionnez une date" />
</div>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

My script :

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
        isRTL: false,
        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii',
        autoclose:true,
        language: 'fr'
     });
});
```

This works in every web browser except Firefox on Microsoft only (works on Mac)

Here it how it looks like :

[image]

But in Firefox, it doesn't pop up.

Here is the error message i get from the console log :

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap datepicker error when using other language: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650795/bootstrap-datepicker-error-when-using-other-language-uncaught-typeerror-cannot)

Comment: Based on the answer to the question in the comments, apparently there's an issue when using other language. I hope it helps.

Comment: okay but why firefox specifically ?

Comment: Hard to answer. This is a bug in the component (Bootstrap).